# Flutter Geofire and Firestore reads problem

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, geofirestore

I need to ask for information regarding firestore readings, I developed a simple app that based on the radius(max 10km) finds the people closest to me. 
The problem is that out of 10,000 registered people who use the app at the same time, the firestore readings rise exponentially. I use flutter_geofire plugin for flutter. There is a way to cache this data intelligently? 
In theory firestore saves the calls but I have not understood after various tests for how long.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about caching, but some general advice would be to divide users in sections. When using the gps you detect witch country the person is in with **Reverse Geocoding API** by Google. Further more you use the **administrative_area_level_1** to get the State/Province, or you can probably find other close cities or states with **Reverse Geocoding Api**.

So when user 1 logs in to the app, you will fetch coordinates, use Google API and get Country: UK, ClosestCity: London, NearbyCities: [oxford,cambridge,...].

Then write in firestore.

```
cities -> UK -> London -> rendomgeneratedId - {userinfo&coordinates}
cities -> UK -> Oxford -> rendomgeneratedId - {userinfo&coordinates}
cities -> UK -> Cambridge -> rendomgeneratedId - {userinfo&coordinates}
```

Now when user 2 who lives in Oxford sets the radius to 10km, the app gets user 2 coordinates -> finds user 2's country, current city and nearby cities.
And does a search in Cloud Firestore with longitute & latitude:

```
//Search in Oxford
cities.UK.Oxford.rendomgeneratedId.where("longitute", "<", 100) 
cities.UK.Oxford.rendomgeneratedId.where("longitute", ">", 50) 
//same for latitude

//Search in London
cities.UK.London.rendomgeneratedId.where("longitute", "<", 100) 
cities.UK.London.rendomgeneratedId.where("longitute", ">", 50) 

etc.
```

I recomend utsing Flutter package LatLong for calculating the destination point 0.5km from center:

```
final Distance distance = const Distance();
final num distanceInMeter = (EARTH_RADIUS * math.PI / 4).round();

final p1 = new LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
final p2 = distance.offset(p1, distanceInMeter, 180);

// LatLng(latitude:-45.219848, longitude:0.0)
print(p2.round());
```

[Flutter latlong](https://pub.dev/packages/latlong)

Comment: thanks for reply, i use this approach in the app, my problem is to large data in the same time, the geoflutter plugin furthermore not support the limit() result, so i cant build a pagination.

Comment: I see, is it because the user object has too much data? Or that the collection is too big?

Comment: Because the collection is too big and the firebase reads are to much.